# Counting the number of .txt files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to count the number of `.txt` files in a Windows 10 directory.

I am starting with the following code as a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%f in (*.*) do echo %%f
```

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

The method will most likely depend upon the rest of the script; but for the question only.

Probably the simplest method would be to use `where.exe` and `find.exe` together:

```bat
Where .:*.txt 2>Nul|Find /C /V ""
```

Should you wish to save the count as the value content of a variable, you can use a `For /F` loop incorporating either `where.exe` or the `Dir` command. Please note however that in both a standard `For` loop, *(`For %%A In (*.txt)`)*, and when using the `Dir` command, *(`Dir *.txt`)*, file extensions beginning with `.txt` are returned as opposed to those ending with `.txt`, returned by `where.exe`. In order to account for this, in my `Dir` version, I have piped the results through a `findstr.exe` to ensure that only `.txt` files are counted:

`Where` method:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "#=0"
For /F %%A In ('"Where .:*.txt 2>Nul|Find /C /V """')Do Set "#=%%A"
Echo(%#%
Pause
```

`Dir` method:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "#=0"
For /F %%A In ('"Dir/B/A-D-L *.txt 2>Nul|FindStr/I "txt$"|Find /C /V """'
)Do Set "#=%%A"
Echo(%#%
Pause
```

Comment: `for /f %A in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt 2^>nul^|find /c /v "'') do echo %A`

Comment: `Dir *.txt` does not output only `.txt` files, it outputs files with extensions beginning with `.txt`. Additionally, I do not see any benefit in piping the output from `Dir` through an external `find.exe` or `findstr.exe` executable for this task, and if I did, I would need to change it to `Dir/B/A-D-L *.txt 2>Nul|FindStr/I "\.txt$"|Find /C /V ""`, _(appropriately escaped if used in a `For` loop)_.

Comment: For ~38.500 files: Mine: <2 sec. Yours: ~ 2min 35sec . `For /F %A In ('Dir/B/A-D-L /s *.csv 2^>Nul^|FindStr/IEC:".csv"^|Find /C /V "" ') Do echo %A` same as mine (<2sec). `find /c` is *very* efficient.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan for the information regarding the speeds, I have revisited my answer and adjusted it to replace my `Set /A` with `Set` after piping through `Find` and/or `FindStr`.

Comment: That's what I like on SO: working together to get the best solution. `:)`